# Trying to pass AuthContext to react component

Tags: reactjs, redux

App.js

```
const GlobalState = (props) => {
  return (
    <AuthState>
      <AlertState>
        <ProfileState>
          <PeersState>
            <GroupsState>
              {props.children}
            </GroupsState>
          </PeersState>
        </ProfileState>
      </AlertState>
    </AuthState>
  )
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <GlobalState>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router history={history}>
            <Container maxWidth="x1">
              <Navbar />
              <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
              <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              {/* <Route exact path= "/link" component={Link}/> */}
              {/* <Route exact path= "/njangui" component={CreateGroup}/>
            <Route exact path= "/njanguis" component={GroupList}/> */}
              {/* <Route exact path= "/njangui" component={groupsContext}/> */}
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/njangui" component={CreateGroup} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/njanguis" component={GroupList} />
              </Switch>
            </Container>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
      </GlobalState>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

AuthContext

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const authContext = createContext();

export default authContext;
```

AuthReducer

```
import { REGISTER_SUCCESS, REGISTER_FAIL, USER_LOADED, AUTH_ERROR, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAIL, LOGOUT, CLEAR_ERRORS } from '../types';

export default (state, action) => {
    console.log(action);
    switch (action.type) {
        
        case USER_LOADED:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                loading: false,
                user: action.payload
            }

        case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                loading: false
            }
        
        case REGISTER_FAIL:
        case AUTH_ERROR:
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            return {
                ...state,
                token: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload
            }

        case LOGOUT:
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            return {
                ...state,
                token: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                loading: false,
                error: null
            }

        case CLEAR_ERRORS:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null
            }

        default:
            return state;

    }
}
```

FormLogin

```
const FormLogin = props => {
  
  const [showPassword, setShowPassord] = useState(false);
  const [remember, setRemember] = useState(true);

  const handleTogglePassword = () => setShowPassord(!showPassword);
  const handleToggleRemember = () => setRemember(!remember);


  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext);
  const { login, error, clearErrors, isAuthenticated, history } = authContext;
  const { setAlert } = alertContext;

  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      console.log(props);
      console.log('YES')
      props.props.history.push('/dashboard')
      //props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }

    if (error !== null) {
      setAlert(error, 'danger');
      clearErrors();
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [error, isAuthenticated, props.history]);

  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  })
  
  const { email, password } = user;

  const onChange = e => setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  // hook form
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,

    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      rememberUser: true,
    },
  });

  // prevent Default
  const preventDefault = (e) => e.preventDefault();

  // form submit
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const userData = {
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password
    };
    console.table(data);
    console.log(data)

    if (userData.email === '') {
      setAlert("Please enter an email", "danger");
    } else if (userData.password === '') {
      setAlert("Please enter a password", "danger");
    } else {

      login(userData);
      console.log(props)
    }
   
  };

  // const onChange = e => {
  //   // this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  //   console.log(e.target);
  // };

  // for reset
  // couldn't make it work

  return (
    <FormStyle component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {/* Email */}
      <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        key="email"
        onChange={onChange}
        fullWidth
        type="email"
        label="Email address"
        error={errors.email ? true : false}
        helperText={errors.email && "Enter a valid email address"}
        {...register("email", { required: true })}
      />

      {/* Password */}
      <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth
        onChange={onChange}
        type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <IconButton edge="end" onClick={handleTogglePassword}>
                {showPassword ? <RiEyeFill /> : <RiEyeOffFill />}
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
        label="Password"
        error={errors.password ? true : false}
        helperText={
          errors.password && "Enter a valid password (5-15 characters)"
        }
        {...register("password", {
          required: true,
          minLength: 5,
          maxLength: 15,
        })}
      />

      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        {/* Checkbox */}
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              className="ckbox"
              checked={remember}
              onChange={handleToggleRemember}
            />
          }
          label="Remember me"
          {...register("rememberUser")}
        />

        <Link href="#" onClick={preventDefault} underline="always">
          Forgot password?
        </Link>
      </Box>

      <Button type="submit" variant="contained" disableElevation>
        Login
      </Button>
    </FormStyle>
  );
};


export default FormLogin;
```

Login.js

```
class Login extends Component {
  static contextType = AuthContext;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    //this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      //context: FormLogin,
     // children: this.props.AuthContext,
      isAuthenticated: "",
      curentUser: '',
      user: [],
      errors: {}
    };
  }





  componentDidMount() {

  
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }

    if(nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated){
      console.log('here')
    }

    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
    console.log(e.target)
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    console.log(userData);
    this.props.loginUser(userData);
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    
    //const { classes } = this.props;
    //const {isAuthenticated,  } = this.props
    return (



      <>
        {/* Helmet */}
        <Helmet>
          <title>Login | MUI Dash</title>
        </Helmet>

        <ContainerBoxStyle container>
          <LeftPanel
            title="Hi, Welcome Back"
            imgAlt="Login Image"
          />

          <RightPanelStyle>
            <Typography paragraph className="account_switch">
              Don't have an account?{" "}
              <Link to="/register" underline="none">
                Get started
              </Link>
            </Typography>

            <Container maxWidth="xs" className="form_Container">
              <Typography variant="h4">Sign in to MUI Dash</Typography>
              <Typography paragraph color="textSecondary">
                Enter your details below.
              </Typography>

              {/* Buttons */}
              <AuthButtonGroup />

              {/* Section Divider */}
              <SectionDivider />

              {/* The Actual Form  */}
              <FormLogin props = {this.contextType} />
            </Container>
          </RightPanelStyle>
        </ContainerBoxStyle>
      </>






    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,

};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors,
});

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
  ), withStyles(styles)
)(Login);
```

I am Stuck trying to figure out how to pass the IsAuthenticated value from the context back to login.js. I tried doing a props.history.push from the useEffect method in the loginForm but that doesn't work. How do i then pass the state from the Form to the login page or vie versa